# Debian VPS based Proxies only work on some websites. How to troubleshoot?

Tags: proxy

I originally posted this questions on Serverfault since it seemed that my server was at least partially “broken”, hence “faulted”. A User (djdomi) on that forum said that I had mis-posted. He/she locked my post and later the post was completely deleted. He/she suggested that I post on Superuser. So here I am. I have corrected one small typo.

Hope you don’t delete me.

Now the post ….

I have tried a few proxies on a Debian 11 VPS, with partial success.
My goal is simply to hide my originating IP address.

I have tried:

1. Tiny Proxy (HTTP / HTTPS proxy)
2. SSH tunneling
3. squid
4. microsocks

The first 3 work for most sites (70%).
Approximately 30% of sites REFUSE access, citing “security issues”.
I have shopped at vitacost.com for years, but cannot access it with proxy.

The usual error message is:

```
Secure Connection Failed
An error occurred during a connection to www.vitacost.com.
 The page you are trying to view cannot be shown because the authenticity of the received data could not be verified.
 Please contact the website owners to inform them of this problem.
```

Oh BTW #1: I had the Express VPN service for 1 year and regardless of the Ips I chose, Express VPN failed for the very same 30% of sites mentioned above. Furthermore, a bit of research revealed that there are publicly available lists of the IP addresses used by popular VPNs. Yikes!

Oh BTW #2: I was surprised that the SSH tunneling did not work. My understanding is that it was a pure tunnel.

I cannot get the 4th proxy to work for any site.
Error is:

```
HTTPS-Only Mode Alert
Secure Site Not Available
You’ve enabled HTTPS-Only Mode for enhanced security, and a HTTPS version of duckduckgo.com is not available.
Learn More…
What could be causing this?
    Most likely, the website simply does not support HTTPS.
    It’s also possible that an attacker is involved. If you decide to visit the website, you should not enter any sensitive information like passwords, emails, or credit card details.
If you continue, HTTPS-Only Mode will be turned off temporarily for this site.
```

In my long journey (8 weeks) to get a universally working proxy, I created a php-driven web page that shows every possible header and status that I could find, and I put it on one of my websites.

I look at more than 80 different parameters, such as:

```
1 HTTP_VIA ____________________ no -
2 HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR ________ no -
3 HTTP_FORWARDED_FOR __________ no -
4 HTTP_X_FORWARDED ____________ no -
5 HTTP_FORWARDED ______________ no -
6 HTTP_CLIENT_IP ______________ no -
7 HTTP_FORWARDED_FOR_IP _______ no -
8 VIA _________________________ no -
9 X_VIA _______________________ no -
10 X_FORWARDED_FOR _____________ no -
11 FORWARDED_FOR _______________ no -
12 X_FORWARDED _________________ no -
13 FORWARDED ___________________ no -
```

Carefully line-by-line I compared the php outputted page when using no proxy and the outputted page when using the squid proxy.

There were only 3 differences.
2 differences were time stamps so I ignored them.

The 3rd difference was the Remote Port.
When I did NOT use a proxy the Remote Port that was reported by my PHP page, was down in the 3,000 range.
With the squid proxy it was above 40,000.
One time it was 42,118.  Another time it was 51,300

Could this be what is detected by the websites that block my access?

Question 1
Any tips on how I can further troubleshoot why some sites reject my traffic?

Question 2
While I know that you probably don’t want to make recommendations in case that causes a “stir”, but gosh anyway, I will ask if you have, any recommendations on an open source proxy that might actually work 100% of sites?

I only need the proxy to work for browsing (Firefox or Librewolf).

Many thanks,
xstack

Comment: Check the certificate that is shown for a website that doesn't work.

Comment: Hello harrymc. Thank you for post.